# Mongoid: How to prevent undefined fields from being created by mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mass-assignment

Here's the code:

```
class M
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
end

params = { name: "foo", age: 20 }
M.create(params)
#=> #<M name: "My Name", age: 20>
```

Notice that `age` wasn't defined, yet it was saved.

This is problematic (potentially a source of DoS) because a malicious user can add any parameters in POST and unknown fields with a large string can sneak in. (e.g. `name=foo&bogus=#{'x'*1000000}`)

So far, I couldn't find anything but `attr_accessible`, but it's not really great for Mongoid as you have to maintain the same field names in both `field` and `attr_accessible` all the time, in all models. Not DRY.

I think the `attr_accessible` API is great for ActiveRecord, because there **a.** you don't explicitly define fields in the models (DRY) and **b.** it's guaranteed there's no chance that a nonexistent field gets saved to RDB. But for Mongoid, I think there should be a better solution than `attr_accessible`.

Note that there's a global config setting `allow_dynamic_fields` but it's not about mass assignment so it's out of the scope in this discussion, however I think it should actually be a per-model macro and should also take care of mass-assignment.

How are you dealing with this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always using `attr_accessible` in models. I rarely found myself including all fields as accessible. Usually there are always a few fields that shouldn't be accessible for mass assignment. If you often need to include every attribute and you're concerned about duplication:

```
attr_accessible *fields.keys
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve this issue, is use a before save callback in my model:

```
set_callback(:save, :before) do |doc|
    (doc.attributes.keys - fields.keys).each { |f| doc.unset(f) }
end
```

This way, even if there are extra attributes they get removed before being saved.